# Why am I getting error while plotting graph?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot two functions in one graph. The first plot is being generated without error. But when I'm adding the code for the second function, I'm getting error

```
 Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `x' or `x@' (in '.3+.8x').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22 {.3+.8x};
              
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
 graph/Expected, line 22

Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `x' or `x@' (in '.3+.8x').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22 {.3+.8x};
              
(That was another \errmessage.)
```

I'm using the following code to obtain the two plots:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = \(N\),
    ylabel = {\(V\)},
]

%v1 being defined
\addplot[domain=2:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{2-.9/x};
\addlegendentry{\(2-.9/N\)}

%v0 being defined
\addplot[domain=2:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{.3+.8x};
\addlegendentry{\(.3+.8N\)}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To my eyes, codes for the first and second plot are identical but still using them together is giving error.

I'm new to latex and am unable to figure out where i have gone wrong.
Would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication is not implicit, you have to use `*` to indicate multiplication. Hence, you need `.3+.8*x`, not `.3+.8x`.

In the second one you have an explicit division operator, `/`, so that works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = \(N\),
    ylabel = {\(V\)},
]

%v1 being defined
\addplot[domain=2:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{2-.9/x};
\addlegendentry{\(2-.9/N\)}

%v0 being defined
\addplot[domain=2:10, 
    samples=2, % <-- you're plotting a straight line, so strictly speaking two samples is enough
    color=blue,
]
{.3+.8*x};
\addlegendentry{\(.3+.8N\)}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! i cant believe i didnt realize the multiplication thing!